# Using URLFetch in Python GAE to fetch a complete document

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I am using urlfetch.fetch in App engine using Python 2.7.

I tried fetching 2 URLs belonging to 2 different domains. For the first one, the result of urlfetch.fetch includes results after resolving XHR queries that are made for getting recommended products. 
However for the other page belonging to another domain, the XHR queries are not resolved and I just get the plain HTML for the most part. The XHR queries for this page are also made for purposes of getting recommended products to show, etc.

Here is how I use urlfetch:
fetch_result = urlfetch.fetch(url, deadline=5, validate_certificate=True)

URL 1 (the one where XHR is resolved and the response is complete)
https://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-15-f222wm-ndash-15.6-Laptop-Touchscreen-Windows-10-Home-Intel-Pentium-Quad-Core-Processor-4GB-Memory-500GB-Hard-Drive/53853531

URL 2 (the one where I just get the plain HTML for the most part)
https://www.flipkart.com/oricum-blue-486-loafers/p/itmezfrvwtwsug9w?pid=SHOEHZWJUMMTEYRU

Can someone please advice what I may be missing in regards to the inconsistency.

Comment: It isn't possible for urlfetch to execute javascript scripts on the page and include their results.  What makes you think that urlfetch is somehow including the results of xhr requests in its result?

Comment: You can do a urlfetch.fetch for URL1 that I've specified, and compare its output to the HTML source in a browser. You will see the content is different. A portion of the difference comes from other products shown on the page - this is fetched via XHR as seen from Chrome developer console. To be clear, I did not expect urlfetch.fetch to execute JS etc., but was a bit surprised in this case that its result seemed different from the plain HTML source content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is serving different output based on the user-agent string supplied in the request headers.

By default, `urlfetch.fetch` will send requests with the user agent header set to something like `AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: myapp.appspot.com`.

A browser will send a user agent header like this: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0`

If you override the default headers for `urlfetch.fetch`

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
urlfetch.fetch(url, headers=headers)
```

you will find that the html that you receive is almost identical to that served to the browser.